# How to Update Apps using In-App update on android 10

Tags: android, android-10.0

I'm trying to update program using in-app update on android and the whole update steps complete successfully on android devices with android version except version 10Q. On this version of android, the update dialog shows and the update of software completes successfully but the progress bar and the page which shows that update is successfully done is not shown and the program closes. I've googled for hours and not found any solution. Whats wrong with my code? 
Any help is appreciated.

> Create and install status receiver

```
final String PACKAGE_INSTALLED_ACTION =
                    "com.example.android.apis.content.SESSION_API_PACKAGE_INSTALLED";
Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, InstallReceiver.class);
intent.setAction(PACKAGE_INSTALLED_ACTION);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 3439,intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
session.commit(pendingIntent.getIntentSender());
session.close();
```

> Reciever part

```
public final class InstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context,  Intent intent) {
    int status = intent.getIntExtra("android.content.pm.extra.STATUS", -1);
    if (status == -1) {
        Intent activityIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT);
        activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(activityIntent);
    } else if (status == 0) {
        (new ToneGenerator(5, 100)).startTone(25);
    } else {
        String msg = intent.getStringExtra("android.content.pm.extra.STATUS_MESSAGE");
        Log.e("AppInstaller", "received " + status + " and " + msg);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do an In App Update, you have to follow the docs:

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates

Check if update available:

```
// Creates instance of the manager.
val appUpdateManager = AppUpdateManagerFactory.create(context)

// Returns an intent object that you use to check for an update.
val appUpdateInfoTask = appUpdateManager.appUpdateInfo

// Checks that the platform will allow the specified type of update.
appUpdateInfoTask.addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
    if (appUpdateInfo.updateAvailability() == UpdateAvailability.UPDATE_AVAILABLE
        // For a flexible update, use AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE
        && appUpdateInfo.isUpdateTypeAllowed(AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE)
    ) {
        // Request the update.
    }
}
```

Start an Update

```
appUpdateManager.startUpdateFlowForResult(
    // Pass the intent that is returned by 'getAppUpdateInfo()'.
    appUpdateInfo,
    // Or 'AppUpdateType.FLEXIBLE' for flexible updates.
    AppUpdateType.IMMEDIATE,
    // The current activity making the update request.
    this,
    // Include a request code to later monitor this update request.
    MY_REQUEST_CODE)
```

List for result of update:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent) {
    if (requestCode == MY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode != RESULT_OK) {
            log("Update flow failed! Result code: $resultCode")
            // If the update is cancelled or fails,
            // you can request to start the update again.
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what your code is doing, but it is not following this example.

I thought your problem might be checking for stalled updates, therefore you should try this:

```
// Checks that the update is not stalled during 'onResume()'.
// However, you should execute this check at all app entry points.
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    appUpdateManager
        .appUpdateInfo
        .addOnSuccessListener { appUpdateInfo ->
            ...
            // If the update is downloaded but not installed,
            // notify the user to complete the update.
            if (appUpdateInfo.installStatus() == InstallStatus.DOWNLOADED) {
                popupSnackbarForCompleteUpdate()
            }
        }
}
```